# View with subviews placed at bottom of screen moving other views

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, constraints

So i've been trying to implement a view, that upon a press of a button, slides up into visibility in a standard `UIViewController`

Additionally, I would like there to be no status bar visible.

I am currently using this method to hide the status bar:

```
var app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
app.setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Slide)
```

To start off, I have positioned the view and the button like so:

[image]

However, when I add a textfield and/or a button to the view at the bottom (as child elements), strange things start happening:

[image]

I have color coded the `UIView`'s so that you can see which views are where. The dark blue is the superview of the VC, where the black is another `UIView` that is set to be centered X and Y in the superview and equal in width and height to the superview. The light blue is the view that I eventually want to be sliding in, however it is currently set so that it's bottom is equal to the superviews bottom.

The REALLY strange thing, is that this ONLY occurs on a **real device**. The constraints work exactly as intended on the simulator, however when testing on my iPhone 5s (on iOS 7.1) this occurs.

Any ideas would be helpful... I have tried more ways around this then is worth mentioning!

Comment: Are you using auto layout? It behaves differently on iOS 7 and 8. It also looks like your black view is not having its position corrected after you hide the status bar. Please post your code that's positioning the views, and show when they are being added, and when the status bar is removed.

Comment: I am indeed using auto-layout. There is no code positioning the views, this is all done completely with interface builder. The only code is the 2 lines I included that removes the status bar. When I don't run these two lines the same thing happens. All dependent on whether I include the text field or button in the bottom view.

Comment: Are you able to send me a sample project to have a look at?

Comment: Sure thing, don't have a github but i've uploaded the zip here. [link](http://www83.zippyshare.com/v/syl9JTgD/file.html)

Comment: PS. I tried setting "Status-bar is initially hidden" in info.plist to NO. (It is currently set to YES) and it fixed the position.... UNTIL the code for hiding the status bar is run, in which case the same issue occurs. So you are right about the status bar being involved.